# Xml file contents not showing up in list on Wamp

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, wamp

I have recently started using ajax methods after going to W3schools and I tried to implement the teachings in a video I saw.
The video is:
http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=ajax+read+xml+file+example&view=detail&mid=815376B884B91D80047D815376B884B91D80047D&first=0&FORM=NVPFVR

I have done the codings and put the files in the www page of Wamp. I open up local host and try to load the data in the xml file but there no data is loaded into the `<ul>` tag I kept empty for the ajax load process.

Here is the code for the website which I named Website.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="central_contents">
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main">

<ul>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="MyJquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The jquery file which I named Myjquery.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
corporateData();                           
//You must also set the time interval in which ajax reloads the page.
fetch();
});


function fetch(){   //this is a function that will update data in the site using ajax
setTimeout(function(){
                    corporateData();
                    fetch();  /*this is the neat part. the function is used to refresh the data and it calls itself after
                    a thousand milliseconds (after every second). So the page will keep on refreshing after every
                    1 second always
                    */
                    },1000);    
}


function corporateData(){

$.ajax({
                    url: "corporateData.xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function(data){
                    $("ul").children.remove();
                    $(data).find("employee").each(function(){                      /*.each here means we must do this for each employee in the xml file*/
                        var info='<li>Name: '+$(this).find("name").text()+'</li><li>Age: '+$(this).find("age").text()+'</li><li>Company: '+$(this).find("company").text()+'</li>';
                        $(ul).append(info);                                          
                     });      //.each() end

           }

});   //$.ajax end

} //corporateData() end
```

Here is the XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<corporate>
<employee>
    <name>Ahmed</name>
    <age>20</age>
    <company>Yellowcorp</company>
</employee>
</corporate>
```

What I want to achieve:
I just want to read the data in the xml file into the empty `<ul>` tags I have put in the HTML file. I run them in local host of wamp and so far have had no results

Comment: Just saying,  As for the comments in the ajax/javascript file, they are more for me than for you cause I am a novice

Comment: What folder is the file `corporate.xml` located in?

Comment: Thank you
It is in the same file as all the other website files. The folder has the html css jquery and xml. (I put the file in the www folder of wamp).

After I posted this question, I have downloaded and tried an xml file from another site. Even that doesnt work on my wamp local host. Yet it works on their site just fine.

Any idea on whats wrong with my Wamp server?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if its not working lets start by removing some of the complexity. Lets start by removing the setTimeout complexity.

`By the way if you want more than one visitor at a time doing this once evry second seems like a good way to cripple your server'

Try this to see what errors you might be getting. Also run it with the browsers debugger. You can set breakpoints and view variables then to see what happening.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getXMLFile();                           
});


function getXMLFile(){

    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "corporateData.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert('getXMLFile failed with ' + textStatus);
            },
            success: function(data, status){
                alert( 'getXMLFile status = ' + status );
                // did I get data returned
                alert( 'getXMLFile data = ' + data );
                $("ul").children.remove();
                $(data).find("employee").each(function() {
                    var info = '<li>Name: ' + $(this).find("name").text() + 
                               '</li><li>Age: ' + $(this).find("age").text() + 
                                '</li><li>Company: ' + $(this).find("company").text() + '</li>';
                    $(ul).append(info);                                          
                 });
       }

    });   //$.ajax end

} //end getXMLFile
```